# Saving and opening TIF raster file with pyqgis fails

Tags: raster, tiff, layer, qgis, pyqgis

I am facing quite a strange issue when handling a raster file with pyqgis.

First, if I manually open the file in QGIS (version 3.22), the raster layer is displayed correctly.

The problem arises when I try to do this with pyqgis. I notice 2 problems :

- I have a correct QGIS project that I made manually. With pyqgis, when I save my qgis project, the source of the raster file is messed up.

For example, if my file path is "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\toto.tif", when saved by pyqgis it becomes "C:/Users/MyUser/Documents/PROJECT/Tests/QGIS/toto.tif"... But my file path was never changed ! "C:/Users/frcoud/Documents/PROJECT/Tests/QGIS" is the directory where my qgis project is being saved. It seems pyqgis confuses the layer source and the directory where the qgz project is being saved.

Here is the code I use to save the qgis project :

```
    QgisFileName = setQgisFileName(myDirectory, myFileName)
    project = QgsProject.instance()
    project.write(QgisFileName)
```

- Second, with pyqgis again, when I try to open the raster file as follows, with the correct path, I get an error saying that the file is invalid:

  ```
    rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(myGeotiffPath, myGeotiffName, "ogr")
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
  ```

I even tried this directly in the QGIS console, it still fails.

It should not be invalid. When I open it manually, it works fine.
I have no such problem with my vector layers.

Can someone explain to me why QGIS/pyqgis has such a behaviour ?